# Passing Proptypes.shape to Proptypes.arrayOf in react

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have created two models State and City in separate files. Importing City in the State.

State can have an array of Cities inside it.

The below code works fine.

**State.js**

```
let State = PropTypes.shape({
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    cities: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(City))
});
```

**City.js**

```
let City = PropTypes.shape({
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    population: PropTypes.number
});
```

However, when i rewrite the `cities` as

```
let State = PropTypes.shape({
    name: React.PropTypes.string,
    cities: PropTypes.arrayOf(City)
});
```

it gives me warning.

**Summary**:

`cities: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(City))` works.

`cities: PropTypes.arrayOf(City)` doesn't.

It gives me following warning:

`Warning: Failed propType: Property xx of component Xx has invalid PropType notation inside arrayOf. Check the render method of Yy.`

My question is, `City` is a `Proptypes.shape`, then why do I need to mention `Proptypes.shape(City)` again in `Proptypes.arrayOf`?

Comment: Please show the export and import code. The problem is probably there.

Comment: I had the same problem and the problem was the order of the imports and exports.

Answer (score 10):

In your code:

```
let City = PropTypes.shape({
  name: React.PropTypes.string,
  population: PropTypes.number
});
```

What version of React are you using?  You're referencing PropTypes from React.PropTypes and PropTypes.  How are you importing PropTypes?  Are you using the prop-types package?

I am using a similar scenario and it works for me.  What does your render look like and what is the data provided for the prop?

For me, the following absolutely works:

```
cities: PropTypes.arrayOf(City)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue, and on my case, it was because one file was loaded before the other file.

In your case, it could be because `City.js` is not yet loaded when you load `State.js`

Answer (score 0):

I can share what was the problem in my case. This was the code that caused the error:

```
const answerPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    followUps: PropTypes.arrayOf(followUpPropType)
})

const followUpPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
})
```

The problem is that `followUpPropType` was declared after `answerPropType`. So I just inverted their order:

```
const followUpPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
})

const answerPropType = PropTypes.shape({
    author: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    followUps: PropTypes.arrayOf(followUpPropType)
})
```